# Elegant way to stop script executed by cell magic

Tags: python, linux, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I'm executing a Python module using cell magic in Jupyter Lab as a script:

```
%%bash
python -m trainer.task
```

The module task looks as follows:

```
import trainer.model as model
model.train_and_evaluate(arg1, arg2, ...)
```

All in all, a module is executed in JupyterLab as a script which executes itself a process.

When interrupting the kernel, the process does not stop. It's fully clear for me why the process does not stop when clicking on the [image] button and and I can kill it in the Linux console.

However, is there an **elegant way** to stop such a process within JupyterLab?

Comment: Do you need to use the `%%bash` magic?  If you want to have more control over a subprocess it might be better to use the `subprocess` module directly.

Comment: Does it behave better when you run it with `%run -m trainer.task`?